# Can i publish Office add-in without having a corporate/company?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, appsource

I have a website (non-profit) and would like to develop an Office add-in for my users to use. I do not plan to get any money from this website so I don't see a point of registering for a corporate. However, when trying to get my Office add-in published via Microsoft Partner Center, there is a step "Business Verification" in which they verify my business. My add-in gets rejected at this step because obviously I do not have any business/corporate for them to verify. Just wondering whether there is a way to publish an Office add-in without having a company/business?

Answer (score 1):

You can publish the manifest file on your web site, so everybody could install it. You just need to run a web app on any web server and keep the manifest file in sync with a web app URL. IT admins can deploy the add-in for the company while regular users can sideload it.

`AppSource` is more universal and reliable way of deploying for everybody, see [Make your solutions available in Microsoft AppSource and within Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/submit-to-appsource-via-partner-center) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

No you do not need to register and you for sure do not need to be a partner. Why are you going to Partner Center ? All you need to do is publish the add-in on GitHub from VisualStudio (if that is what you are using). Let me know more about how you are developing the add-in and how do you want to distribute it to your users.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish

Comment: I did not use VisualStudio. I followed this example and added my code to the Javascript file. I use Yeoman generator. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-jquery?tabs=yeomangenerator

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to distribute without using AppSource. See the options at [Deploy and publish Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish), especially Centralized Deployment.

Comment: thanks, i may be wrong but that one looks like it is for an organization's internal IT team to publish add-on for that organization's employees to use, right?

Comment: Yes. I thought that was your situation. I've added the office-store tag to your question. This should get the attention of the right people.

Comment: In my case, there is no "internal network". I would like to share my add-in with anyone in the internet who would like to use it